# Browser tab playing audio, yet not visible in mixer

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-10, volume-mixer

My issue is that a tab in Chrome is playing audio, and even shows the speaker icon:

[image: Tab playing audio]

However the mixer does not show the process at all:

[image: The mixer]

What is even weirder is I can co to output devices and test my headset, and the output plays the test audio perfectly.

This issue came after an automatic reboot, and I believe updates may have been installed.

I am using Google Chrome, version `47.0.2526.106 m`, and I am on Windows 10.

UPDATE: the error persists on existing tabs, however a new tab plays audio now.

Comment: i have noticed strange things with the mixer in windows 10. for example, most if not all modern apps (edge, etc) won't show up in the mixer when playing audio

Comment: The Google Chrome tabs that play audio do show up though on a tab by tab basis